# How to make a regex for "Name(2)" words with a parentheses of number

Tags: java, regex, parentheses

I need to make a regex for this

example

math(5),English(6),P.E(5)

Comment: Effort so far ? please post the pattern you have tried ?

Comment: I already have the answer. Thank You :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
(?<=,|^)([^(,]*)\((\d*)\)(?=,|$)
```

might be close to what you have in mind.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?<=,|^)([^(,]*)\\((\\d*)\\)(?=,|$)";
        final String string = "math(5),English(6),P.E(5)";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: math(5)
Group 1: math
Group 2: 5
Full match: English(6)
Group 1: English
Group 2: 6
Full match: P.E(5)
Group 1: P.E
Group 2: 5
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AHLe0d/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/AHLe0d/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---